# Best way to manage 2 classes with nearly identical properties in Java

Tags: java, oop

I want to begin by stating that for reasons beyond the scope of this question, the database cannot be modified.

That being said, the issue is that I have 2 database objects (T1, T2) with nearly identical properties and they share the same UI code and business logic.  Meaning depending on the configuration options the UI is displaying T1 data or T2 data.  All the logic is for managing the data is the same as well.

What I did not want was to have my application logic code littered with `instanceof` operators and basically manage 2 sets of identical code.  So my solution was to create a sort of wrapper class (TCombo) that takes either T1 or T2 as a constructor.  All the getters and setters have the design that resembles

```
public String getProp1() {
    if(o instanceof T1) ((T1)o).getProp1();
    else(o instanceof T2) ((T2)o).getProp1();
}
```

and basically follows that for the setters as well so when i set a value, the DB object gets set correctly.  Doing this has allowed me to use 1 set of code and just manage this TCombo class throughout the code, and this has worked great.  The issue is the efficiency is horrible and since my application deals with large datasets, having to create this TCombo class for every item in the dataset creates horrid loading times.

My question is: What is the best way to manage these classes so I don't have to maintain 2 sets of logic code and also have speed?

Comment: What about class hierarchy and polymorphism? This can be achieved using `interface`s and `abstract class`es.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more or less what interfaces were designed to handle, so you set up an interface named something like `T` with your common getters and setters, and then have both `T1` and `T2` implement it.  The then code that is common to both can pass around references to the interface, and call the common methods without having to use calls to `instanceof`.  This will let you potentially implement custom code in the getters and setters of the individual instances (e.g. if you want to do validation or something in a `set` method of `T1` but not in `T2`, etc)

Another option would be having a common base class that both of your DB objects extend, and this base object contains all of the common fields between them.  Then you just pass around references to the base class.  This has the added benefits of not having to implement the same getters and setters in the same place.

In either case, you will need to use `instanceof` and casting to gain access to the methods unique to `T1` and `T2`, but you should be able to do it much less often.

Comment: Thanks ill look into interfaces.  There are some implementation issues that I'm not sure how to handle based on your descriptions, but I think just some research should solve them pretty easily.

Comment: sounds like an abstract super class is a proper way to go (implement what's the same for both, leave open what's not equal)

Answer (score 4):

you should take a look to interfaces, you could create an interface an let T1 and T2 implement the interface. then you only need to make either a T1 or T2 instance and your code works. You could also take a look for the liskov subtitution principle.